# Passing in multiple api link into a service and getting all results into an array

Tags: javascript, angular

Is it possible to make an API get call using multiple links from an array and gather it results into an array of objects.

Let's say the sampleArr is an array of links

```
 sampleArr = [
 "https://api.abc.com/users/xut",
 "https://api.abc.com/users/yre",
 "https://api.abc.com/users/wer",
 "https://api.abc.com/users/cdw"
]
```

and I am making an API call using this UserService

```
this.userService.getUser(sampleArr)
    .subscribe(data => console.log(data)) // should log an array of the results
```

**UserService**

```
getUser(url: string): Observable<any> {
  return this.http.get<User[]>(url)
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try using `forkJoin` or `combineLatest` operators.

Try this:

```
import { combineLatest } from 'rxjs';

combineLatest(
  ...sampleArr.map(url => this.userService.getUser(url)), 
// this.userService.getUser("https://api.abc.com/users/xut"), this.userService.getUser("https://api.abc.com/users/yre"),....
).subscribe(arrayOfResults => {
   console.log(arrayOfResults);
});
```